# How to use full disk encryption on the second self-encrypting disk?

Tags: linux, ssd, bios, grub2, fde

My laptop has two self-encrypting SSD disks:

- (1) one installed the usual way,
- (2) another one in a caddy that you stick into the optical drive bay.

I was able to set the HDD password on (1) using the settings in the BIOS and get a password prompt on boot but there doesn't seem to be any way to set the password on (2).

Just to see what happens I used `hdparm` to set the password on (2) and it did the job but there was still no way to unlock the disk on boot. As a result GRUB which lives on (1) complained that it couldn't find the boot partition which currently lives on (2).

Is there a way to make this set-up work? Does GRUB have support for unlocking SEDs?

Comment: Likely not the answer you want but you should be using LUKS encryption on both. At least you can set up LUKS for the removable one